# Return a reference to unpacked dictionary in Python

Tags: python, reference, return-value, argument-unpacking

There is a common way to pass arguments in Python like this:

```
def foo(a1, a2):
    print(a1, a2)
    
def my_dict():
    return {'a1': 4, 'a2':5}

foo(**my_dict())
```

...

```
4 5
```

But now I want to move the asterisks inside my_dict function:

```
def foo(a1, a2):
    print(a1, a2)
    
def my_dict():
    return **{'a1': 4, 'a2':5}

foo(my_dict())
```

...

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way to achieve such behavior in Python? I am dealing with third-party code and can modify my_dict function, but can't modify foo(my_dict()) call.

Comment: `**` is part of the function calling syntax. You can't move it into the function, "unpacked dictionary" is not a thing.

Comment: Can you modify `foo`? You need to change it so it just gets a single argument.

Comment: If it calls `foo(my_dict())`, it expects `foo()` to be defined like `def foo(my_dict):`. The function is expected to extract the dictionary elements itself, not unpack them in the parameter list.